# Connecting to my WiFi using BSSID and password in wpa_supplicant.conf always fails. Why?

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

I have a WiFi network consisting of multiple WiFi APs exposing the name SSIDs, a mesh.

Now I have a Raspberry Pi which should connect to one specific AP only. This can usually be achieved by specifying the BSSID of this specific AP, rather than the SSID.

My `wpa_supplicant.conf` looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

network={
  bssid=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
  psk="mypassword"
}
```

Only the lines `bssid` and `psk` are of relevance here.

Using `ssid` and the correct password works fine.

Problem: Using `bssid` instead of `ssid` using the same correct password results in the WiFi connection failing to connect.

Comment: You can specify both.

Comment: Both what? Bssid and ssid? This misses the point as my goal is not to connect to a random AP but only to a specific one, thus ssid is ruled out.

Comment: The specficity is specified with `bssid`, the generality is specified with `ssid`.

Comment: So you are saying that I can specify `bssid` and `ssid` and it will ignore `ssid` when looking for an AP to connect to, but it will honour `ssid` when encoding the password when connecting to the `bssid`? How bizarr, yet useful. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `bssid` the password must be specified as a 64-char hex string, like so:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

network={
  bssid=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
  psk=06386536cc5efd03f3fa84aa8ea2cc8408973df34bd84b53806eed3023cda67e
}
```

The 64-bit hex password is calculated from the SSID (not BSSID) and the ASCII password as follows:

```
wpa_passphrase <SSID> <password>
```

Manpage of `wpa_passphrase`:

- https://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_passphrase

Linux manpage of `wpa_supplicant.conf`, not helpful:

- https://linux.die.net/man/5/wpa_supplicant.conf

FreeBSD manpage of `wpa_supplicant.conf` (not specifying the need to specify a 64-char hex password for bssid either):

- https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?wpa_supplicant.conf(5)

Comment: This *looks like* a good answer. It might be x-good if you'd add a reference to some documentation - a `man` page, a blog, another SE Q&A, etc.  As it's written, it might discourage some from up-voting your answer because they can't verify it's correct.

Comment: Thats the thing: The password behavior is not documented anywhere. This is why I entered the question and the answer in the first place. There is an inconclusive thread about this on the Raspberry Pi forum which is locked, so nobody can answer the unanswered question there. Pretty annoying.